# When I choose item in jList and use getSelectedIndex() it returns -1

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I am trying to make a ToDoList , and I create a `jButton` to remove a Task from the `Database` ,when i check the `index` it always gives (-1)

```
        if (jListTasks.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No task selected!!");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure?!", "Remove task", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);}
```

update:

```
//      set DefaultListModel
        tasksListModel = new DefaultListModel();
        jListTasks.setModel(tasksListModel);
```

Then I create this method

```
// to clear and fill list every time method invoked
    private void fillTaskList() {

        tasksListModel.clear();
        try {
            resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
//                System.out.println("xxx");
                tasksListModel.addElement("\"" + resultSet.getString("task_name") +
                        "\"" + " starts at " + resultSet.getString("start_time"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ToDoFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

and this is the `ActionListener` of the `RemoveButton`

```
jbtnRemoveTask.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
// to fill the list with latest values in database
            sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tasks";
            try {
                pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
                fillTaskList();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ToDoFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
// to restore the Frame to default size as I change size during the using of application
            if (ToDoFrame.this.getSize().width > 515 || ToDoFrame.this.getSize().height > 440) {
// implementation for these two methods comes at the end
                decreaseHeight();
                decreaseWidth();
            }
//          System.out.println(jListTasks.getLastVisibleIndex());
//          System.out.println(jListTasks.getSelectedIndex());

// this code is always executed even there is item selected
            if (jListTasks.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No task selected!!");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure?!", "Remove task", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                try {
//                  System.out.println(jListTasks.getSelectedValue());
                    String s = jListTasks.getSelectedValue().toString();
                    s = s.substring(s.length() - 5);
//                    System.out.println(s);
// the code for updating database
                    sqlUpdate = "DELETE FROM tasks WHERE start_time = ?";
                    pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);
                    pstmt.setString(1, s);
                    pstmt.executeUpdate();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Task removed successfully!");
                    sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tasks";
                    pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
                    fillTaskList();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ToDoFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        });

// here are the code of decreaseWidth and decreaseHeight methods
private void decreaseWidth() {

    for (int i = ToDoFrame.this.getSize().width; i > 510; i -= 10) {
        ToDoFrame.this.setSize(i, ToDoFrame.this.getSize().height);
        ToDoFrame.this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ToDoFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}

 private void decreaseHeight() {

    for (int i = ToDoFrame.this.getSize().height; i > 435; i -= 10) {
        ToDoFrame.this.setSize(ToDoFrame.this.getSize().width, i);
        ToDoFrame.this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ToDoFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** the code was working perfectly before making methods to re-size the `Frame` , when doing the re-sizing directly inside the `ActionListener`

Thanks for help

Comment: Please provide more code.

Comment: Is anything actually selected?

Comment: well it be good to see how `jListTasks` is being populated

Comment: And also to see what happens in that jbutton action.

Comment: One of two things is happening: 1) the user hasn't selected anything in the list, or 2) you don't have a reference to the JLIst that is visible on the GUI. Since you didn't post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with your question we can't help you with any more advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the action listener of your remove button calls the `fillTaskList` method before retrieving the selected index. The refill of the todo list will clear the selection in the list and the call to `jListTasks.getSelectedIndex()` will return -1.

I think you only need to update the todo list after removing the selected item.

Comment: IF I do it in a thread do you think it will solve the problem ??

Comment: I don't think it will help. Removing the code for the first update of the todo list ("SELECT * FROM tasks" with the try-catch) seems to be the best solution to me. Updating the list when you are about to remove an item is not very helpful, so deleting this code should make your program shorter and working.

Comment: If you wanted to do the update before the removal anyway, you could first save the index of the item to be removed. After that, you could update the list, use the saved index for the removal, and update the list again.